# service logs podman container timezone is always UTC

Tags: ansible, timezone, podman

I have podman version 3.3.1 and rhel 8.1
podman containers show date as local date ITC timezone
but service running inside container has UTC time in logs

I am using Ansible scripts to run podman

```yaml
- name: "Container {{ container_name }} [Podman]"
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: "{{ container_name }}"
    image: "{{ container_image }}"
    hostname: "{{ container_hostname | default(container_name) }}"
    state: started
    network_mode: host
    security_opt: "label=disable"
    restart_policy: on-failure
    volumes: "{{ container_volumes }}"
    timezone: local
```

peeking Inside container

```
 >> ls -l /etc/localtime
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC
```

Comment: I would recommend you keep using UTC inside the container, but if you want to change it, you should be able to do it when you build the image?

Comment: UTC is best to keep but the requirement is to see logs on server as per location is easier else central log management tool would have save the work- like Datadog